# C# decimal and double

Tags: c#

From what I understand decimal is used for precision and is recommended for monetary calculations. Double gives better range, but less precision and is a lot faster than decimal.

What if I have time and rate, I feel like double is suited for time and decimal for rate. I can't mix the two and run calculations without casting which is yet another performance bottleneck. What's the best approach here? Just use decimal for time and rate?

Comment: What do you mean by time ? milliseconds ? minutes ? Ticks ? All these cases go for long or decimal.

Comment: The best approach depends on your requirements.  As you haven't specified, then you probably really don't have any, which means go decimal and move on.

Comment: Persionally I think [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) is best suited for time. For rate, it depends on what you are doing with it.

Comment: Unless you need an extremely fast speed in a calculation that's executed millions of times, just go for `decimal`.

Comment: You talk a lot about performance issues. Are they real (measured and identified to the double/decimal choice being the cause) ? or do you anticipate a non-existing potential but not sure problem ?

Comment: It is vague, but time and rate tend to be physical properties.  The kind of thing you have to measure, any measurement has an implicit imprecision and they are very rarely less than one part in a million.  Plenty good enough for *double*, it is accurate to one part in a quadrillion, 9 orders of magnitude better than necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant, you are right, but with floating point values sometimes that lack of precision produces outputs like 0.8000001 or 0.9999999, or makes things like `0.1f == 0.1` false. So you will have to be more careful with those types.

Comment: Think that won't happen with Decimal?  Csonole.WriteLine(3m * (1m / 3m))

Comment: That's because decimals are totally precise but up to its limits, it almost makes sense to get that result. With floats you get unexpected values, like 1f / 3f == 0.333333343. How acceptable is that? When you do * 3 again, you are just undoing the previous error float gave you. Decimal will give you 0.3333333333333333333333333333. Also, 0.1f * 1e6 == 100000.00149011612. In all my years, floats have given me much more trouble than decimals (actually I don't remember any problem with decimals). Just see all the issues JavaScript has with floats... The key is to understand the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb is to use the type that is more suitable to the values you will handle. This means that you should use `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` for time, unless you only care about a specific unit, like seconds, days, etc., in which case you can use any integer type. Usually for time you need precision and don't want any error due to rounding, so I wouldn't use any floating point type like `float` or `double`.

For anything related to money, of course you don't want any rounding error either, so you should really use `decimal` here.

Finally, only if for some very specific requirements you need **absolute speed** in a calculation that is **done millions of times** and for which `decimal` happens not to be fast enough, *only then* I would think of using another faster type. I would first try with integer values (maybe multiplying your value by a power of 10 if you have decimals) and only divide by this power of 10 at the end. If this can't be done, *only then* I would think of using a `double`. Don't do a *premature optimization* if you are not sure it's needed.

Comment: Using `double` is not premature optimization, it's the simpler choice.  The whole point of avoiding premature optimization is to avoid complicating your code before you even know if it's worth it.  Trying to use `decimal` or an integral type that you have to scale all over the place is the sort of unnecessary complication that should be avoided.

Comment: I think `decimal` is simpler and gives less headaches. As I commented above, with floating point values sometimes that lack of precision produces outputs like 0.8000001 or 0.9999999, or makes things like `0.1f == 0.1` false. So you have to be more careful with those types. Anyway, we know almost nothing about what haosmark needs, so it's all guessing here.

Comment: I think the same care must be taken in either case because `decimal` is still a floating point type and is still subject to rounding and truncation errors.  It runs into the same sorts of problems but in different situations. So I disagree that it's simpler.  I think this advice makes `decimal` seem like a magic bullet when it isn't.

Comment: You need infinite decimals not to have rounding and truncation. How would you avoid those otherwise? If you exceed the `decimal`'s limits, it's quite logical to suffer those. I have never experienced magical decimals appearing or unexpected inequalities with decimals, I think they are a much more reliable type than the so-called floating point ones. Anyway, nothing is magic in programming and it is obviously not the best solution for every case, but at least for monetary calculations I'd say it's a no-brainer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `double` for both.  `decimal` is for currency or other situations where the base-10 representation of the number is important.  If you don't care about the base-10 representation of a number, don't use `decimal`.  For things like time or rates of change of physical quantities, the base-10 representation generally doesn't matter, so `decimal` is not the most appropriate choice.

The important thing to realize is that `decimal` is still a floating-point type.  It still suffers from rounding error and cannot represent certain "simple" numbers (such as 1/3).  Its one advantage (and one purpose) is that it can represent decimal numbers with fewer than 29 significant digits exactly.  That means numbers like 0.1 or 12345.6789.  Basically any decimal you can write down on paper with fewer than 29 digits.  If you have a repeating decimal or an irrational number, `decimal` offers no major benefits.